# o else do meu progama ativa a cada input?[C++]

Tags: c++, if, matemática, else

estou aprendendo a progamar em c++ e resolvi fazer uma calculadora com as coisas e já aprendi no meu aprendizado, e criei uma mensagem de erro quando o progama não conhecia o comando digitado pelo usuario, o progama esta funcionando como eu queria so que fica mandano essa mensagem de erro a cada cin da função da calculadora que eu criei.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


void help(int help) {
    if (help == 1) {
        std::cout << "---------------help---------------" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "'/help': to open this guide." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "'/calc': to start calculate." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "'/quit': to exit the app." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "'/help calc': to calculate help." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "----------------------------------" << std::endl;
    }
    if (help == 2) {
        std::cout << "---------Calculator help----------" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "'+': Add operation." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "'-': Subtract operation." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "'*': Multiplication operation." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "'/': Divide operation." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "'/calc end': stop calculate" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "----------------------------------" << std::endl;
    }
}
int numberAdd(int number1, int number2) {
    int sum = number1 + number2;
    return sum;
}
int numberSub(int number1, int number2) {
    if (number1 < 0) {
        if(number2 < 0) {
            int sub = numberAdd(number1, number2);
            return sub;
        }
    }
    else {
        int sub = number1 - number2;
        return sub;
    }
}
int numberMut(int number1, int number2) {
    int Mut = number1 * number2;
    return Mut;
}
int numberDiv(int number1, int number2) {
    if (number2 == 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error: cannot divide by 0" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        int Div = number1 / number2;
        return Div;
    }
}
void calc() {
    int calc_run{};
    int mainNumber{};
    int firstNumber{};
    int secndNumber{};
    std::string CalcUC;
    std::cout << "Calculator: " << "'/help calc' to open calc help" << std::endl;
    help(2);
    std::cout << "Calculator: " << "Enter number: ";
    std::cin >> mainNumber;
    while (calc_run != -1) {
        std::cout << "Calculator: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, CalcUC);
        if (CalcUC == "/help calc") {
        help(2);
        }
        else if (CalcUC == "+") {
            std::cout << "Calculator: " << "Enter number: ";
            std::cin >> secndNumber;
            mainNumber = numberAdd(mainNumber, secndNumber);
            std::cout << "Calculator: " << mainNumber << std::endl;
        }
        else if (CalcUC == "-") {
            std::cout << "Calculator: " << "Enter number: ";
            std::cin >> secndNumber;
            mainNumber = numberSub(mainNumber, secndNumber);
            std::cout << "Calculator: " << mainNumber << std::endl;
        }
        else if (CalcUC == "*") {
            std::cout << "Calculator: " << "Enter number: ";
            std::cin >> secndNumber;
            mainNumber = numberMut(mainNumber, secndNumber);
            std::cout << "Calculator: " << mainNumber << std::endl;
        }
        else if (CalcUC == "/") {
            std::cout << "Calculator: " << "Enter number: ";
            std::cin >> secndNumber;
            mainNumber = numberDiv(mainNumber, secndNumber);
            std::cout << "Calculator: " << mainNumber << std::endl;
        }
        else if (CalcUC == "/clear") {
            std::cout << "Calculator: " << "Enter number: ";
            std::cin >> mainNumber;
        }
        else if (CalcUC == "/calc end") {
            std::cout << "exiting Calculator..." << std::endl;
            calc_run = -1;
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Error: invalid command" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    int run{};
    std::string UC;
    std::cout << "'/help' for help" << std::endl;
    while (run != -1) {
        std::getline(std::cin, UC);
        if (UC == "/help") {
            help(1);
        }
        else if (UC == "/help calc") {
            help(2);
        }
        else if (UC == "/calc") {
            std::cout << "opening Calculator..." << std::endl;
            calc();
        }
        else if (UC == "/quit") {
            run = -1;
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Error: invalid command" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sabes em qual `else` de erro está entrando? meu palpite é que `CalcUC` (função `calc()`) não está recebendo um valor correto.

Comment: **Muito obrigado** é isso mesmo mexi um pouco aki e o problema esta ai, agora vou tentar resolver, acredito que tenha sido uma pergunta idiota mas eu to aprendendo ainda to na parte das variaveis eu fiz essa besteira baseado no que eu sei de c#(csharp), valeu pela atenção cara

Comment: **ainda estou procurando o problema mas vou resumir oque eu fiz**

Comment: eu fiz uma variavel de string chamada `CalcUC` ai eu eu coloco para um valor ser atribuido a ela no console e comparo ela com as stings que são os "comandos" do meu progama 
`if(CalcUC == "/help"){
 blablabla;
}
else if(CalcUC == "/blablabla"{
blabla;
}
else{
std::cout << "ERRO QUE ATIVA TODA HORA" << std::endl;
}`
não faço ideia porque esse else ativa a cada vez que ele entra no loop e mesmo o progama funcionando normalmente do jeito que eu pensei. eu simplesmente apagei só que eu queria o erro funcionando

Comment: descobri o problema são os espaços

Answer (score -1):

os `if`s e `else`s não estão lindando bem com os espaços em `CalcUC` mudei o `std::getline(std::cin, CalcUC);` para `std::getline(std::cin >> ws, CalcUC);` e agora os espaços em branco funcionam normalmente. e o erro esta funcionando do jeito que deveria agora.